# Index of value in table with variable row selection

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table like the following:

[image: Example Table]

My problem is the following: I want to be able to get the index of the row of the value, when the value and column are specified.

Example: Col 3 and 1 should output Row 3, Col 1 and 5 should output Row 5.

I know that MATCH() would allow me to get the correct column, but I am unsure how to use that info. Using INDEX(MATCH(), MATCH()) won't get me the proper results as I need to enter the value for the row, which is exactly what I'm looking for. I thinkg the different lookup fonctions have the same issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution based on OFFSET but it being Volatile can slow down the sheet if you have a very large dataset.

See following screenshot. Formula in N4 is

```
=INDEX($E$4:$E$8,MATCH(M4,OFFSET(E3,1,MATCH(L4,$F$3:$I$3,0)):OFFSET(E3,5,MATCH(L4,$F$3:$I$3,0)),0))
```

[image]

In the formula  `...:OFFSET(E3,5...`  change 5 to the actual number of rows that you have in the table.

To avoid OFFSET you can use INDEX to return the Cell Reference rather than Cell Value. The formula with only INDEX is, for the same sample table as above.

```
=INDEX($E$4:$E$8,MATCH(M4,INDEX($F$4:$I$4,MATCH(L4,$F$3:$I$3,0)):INDEX($F$8:$I$8,MATCH(L4,$F$3:$I$3,0)),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this without using OFFSET, which is volatile (recalculate a lot!).

Lets say you have defined names *col* and *val*, and your table as shown starts in A1. Then the `MATCH(col, B1:E1, 0)` is the correct column number to search. Then the correct row number is:

```
="Row " & MATCH(val, INDEX(B2:E6, 1, MATCH(col, B1:E1, 0)):INDEX(B2:E6, 5, MATCH(col, B1:E1, 0)),0)
```

> Or if you really wanted to return the text in column A:
>
> ```
> =INDEX(A2:A6, MATCH(val, INDEX(B2:E6, 1, MATCH(col, B1:E1, 0)):INDEX(B2:E6, 5, MATCH(col, B1:E1, 0)),0))
> ```
>
> Also if you have office 365 and the LET function, you can make it more
> efficient:
>
> ```
> =LET(colindex, MATCH(col, B1:E1, 0), INDEX(A2:A6, MATCH(val, INDEX(B2:E6, 1, colindex):INDEX(B2:E6, 5, colindex),0)))
> ```

Answer (score 0):

And just because its interesting, here is an array formula to get the row number directly:

```
=SUM(IF(B1:F1=col,(B2:F6=val)*ROW(A1:A5),FALSE))
```

In versions prior to Excel 365, enter with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER in inform Excel to treat it as an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=INDEX(A2:A6,MATCH(I2,OFFSET(A2:A6,0, MATCH(H2,B1:E1,0)),0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume your rows and columns are actually named in some less predictable manner, so I've generalized to take that into account. If they actually ARE named as shown, the problem is actually very simple.

So, generalized:

```
=INDEX(A2:A6,  MATCH(G2,  INDIRECT(  ADDRESS(2,  MATCH(G1,B1:E1,0)+1)  &":"&  ADDRESS(6,  MATCH(G1,B1:E1,0)+1)  )))
```

First, you match the column name in the row of column headers. Twice, actually, as you need a start and end to the rows in it to search for the data value. *(The alternative is to use a simple column reference, similar in nature to `D:D` and search a million rows per calculation, but I can't really recommend that.)* Twice because you will use it in the `ADDRESS()` function to get a starting address and ending address for the data item search. In the case of the data you supplied, it will give the string `D2:D6`.

`INDIRECT()` changes that string to a real reference.

The outer `MATCH()` works like any other `INDEX/MATCH` formula, finding the data item in the range and returning its index value, `3` in this case.

Finally, the `INDEX()` uses that... index... to return the first column's value matching that index. Row header `ROW 3` in this case.

Unless you have a rather large data set, and I do mean large, and a computer from before the last 5-8 years, using volatile functions like `OFFSET()` could produce noticeable lag. LARGE. Lots of formulas, not just lots of data and this is the only formula. Or really large in terms of data. You don't specify an earlier version of Excel, so I would guess your computer/s is/are new or newer as well, so that might not affect you. Mine is four+ years old and on another problem here, I filled 30 columns with 100,000 rows of static data and the formula searching it literally only caused about a one second delay. So the volatility warning many folks issue really isn't an issue anymore. I just mention it so someone else won't.